# Java - Matrix of complex numbers

Tags: java

I want to create a class ComplexMatrix that has field a array[NxN] of type ComplexNumber. I already made a ComplexNumber class as you can see below:

```
public class ComplexNumber {

    private double real;
    private double img;

    // Getters and setters
    public double getReal() {
        return real;
    }

    public void setReal(double real) {
        this.real = real;
    }

    public double getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(double img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    // Constructor
    public ComplexNumber(double real, double img) {
        this.real = real;
        this.img = img;
    }

    // Add
    public ComplexNumber addComp(ComplexNumber num) {

        ComplexNumber num1 = new ComplexNumber(real + num.real, img + num.img);

        return num1;
    }

    // Subtract
    public ComplexNumber subtractComp(ComplexNumber num) {

        ComplexNumber num1 = new ComplexNumber(real - num.real, img - num.img);

        return num1;
    }

    // Multiply
    public ComplexNumber multiplyComp(ComplexNumber num) {

        ComplexNumber num1 = new ComplexNumber(real*num.real-img*num.img,real*num.img+img*num.real);

        return num1;
    }

    // Is Equals
    boolean equals(ComplexNumber num) {

        ComplexNumber num1 = new ComplexNumber(real, img);
        if (num.real == num1.real && num.img == num1.img) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        if (img > 0) {
            return getReal() + " + " + Math.abs(getImg()) + "i";
        }
        if (img < 0) {
            return getReal() + " - " + Math.abs(getImg()) + "i";
        }
        if (real==0) {
            return getImg() + "i";
        }
        if (img==0) {
            return getReal() + "";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

that has some methods and its own toString that prints as follows:

```
  3.51 + 1.87i
    2.35 - 5.61i
    -8.45 + 2.65i
```

The implemented `ComplexMatrix` has an array [M][N] as a field, and the cronstructor  `public ComplexMatrix(int rows, int cols)` gives the array 
random numbers from one to ten **using** the method computeRandom. Then a 
`toString()` functions (which also implemets `toSting()` from ComplexNumber class) , should print the random numbers array. A desired print of ComplexMatrix would be:

```
[1.24 + 2.55i, -0.32 + 2.00i, 1.35 - 5.88i;
-5.71 - 5.91i, 0.29 – 9.14i, 0.00 + 3.51i;
6.44 + 0.00i, -3.51 – 0.67i, 2.10 + 4.20i;]
```

Here is ComplexMatrix class:

```
         import java.util.Random;

public class ComplexMatrix {

    private ComplexNumber[][] complexArray;

    // Default Constructor
    public ComplexMatrix() {
        super();
        this.complexArray = null;
    }

    // Copy Constructor
    public ComplexMatrix(ComplexMatrix original) {
        super();
        original.complexArray = complexArray;
    }

    private Random rand = new Random();

    private double computeRandom() {
        int randomNum = (int) ((rand.nextDouble() - 0.5) * rand.nextInt(20) * 100);
        return randomNum / 100.0;
    }

    // Random Numbers Constructor
    public ComplexMatrix(int rows, int cols)  {

        double real = 0;
        double img = 0;

        ComplexNumber[][] complexArray= new ComplexNumber[rows][cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                real = computeRandom();
                img = computeRandom();
                complexArray[i][j] = new ComplexNumber(real, img);
                //edw peiramatizomai..to print 8a ginetai sthn toString()
                System.out.print(complexArray[i][j].toString());
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        int rows = 0,cols = 0;
        //ComplexNumber[][] complexArray= new ComplexNumber[rows][cols];
        ComplexMatrix s = new ComplexMatrix(rows,cols);

        String out = "[";
        //????????????????????????????????????
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                //????????
                out = s.toString();

            }
        out += "]";
        return out;

    }
}
```

Comment: `I have trouble getting around how to populate the array` Can you be more specific?  What is the trouble exactly?

Comment: Maybe this is off-topic to your question, but both equals and multiplication need improvement. Equals does not override Object.equals. multiplication is simply wrong for complex numbers.

Comment: yeah you 're right i'm on it. Any help on implementing toString() of ComplexMatrix class?

Comment: Also for this class equals should be  boolean equals(ComplexNumber num) , so it shouldnt override the Object.equals maybe ?

Comment: What is precisely the problem? Iterate over the rows, for each row iterate over elements in that row. Btw, toString in ComplexNumber looks fishy as well, you probably want something sensible for the strictly real number

Comment: Please edit your post and explicitly tell us what is the problem, what is your goal and please include a simple input and output to help us understand your question. It is advised to first read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post an MCVE which runs without crashing. We are happy to help!

Comment: ok thanks for feedback , changed ComplexNumber class and edited the question

Comment: @DavidDunn - You are missing the point.  We want you to explain specifically what problem you are having implementing the `toString()` method.  Please understand that we are not here to write your code for you.  The point of this exercise is to get you to learn to program.  You will only really learn that if you do the work for yourself; i.e. you work out what needs to be done and you write, test, debug the code.  Lesiak  has already given you hints on what you need to do.

Comment: Ok you're right . What i'm trying to do is give random values to the array that i passed as a field through a constructor as you can see on my code, then a method toString() to print the desired array. I will update what i've tried and if anyone has some hints on how to move on it would be great to share. I hope I've made clear now of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: think computeRandom should function in the right way now

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to give pseudo-code (partly on the assumption that this is an assignment).  But hopefully this gives you enough to get going with an implementation without just plain giving the solution.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    out = "[";
    for (row : rows) {
        if (notFirstRow) {
            out += "\n"; // New line
        }
        for (column : columns) {
            if (notFirstColumn) {
                out += ", ";
            }
            out += matrix[row][column].toString();
        }
    }
    out += "]";
    return out;
}
```

Warning, I make no claims that this is optimal, or that there aren't better ways to format a matrix (or complex numbers)...  But if you can flesh this out to actually compile I suspect you'll have what you're after.

Comment: thank you i will try implementing it. I hope my compleRandom method is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is to print according to your desired format. Here is sample code to achieve this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    out = out.append("[");
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            out.append(String.valueOf(matrix[row][column]));
            //Populate according to whether last column or not.
            out.append(column != columns - 1 ? ", " : ";");
        }
        out.append(row != rows - 1 ? "\n" : "");
    }
    out.append("]");
    return out.toString();
}
```

Just remember, for nested arrays you have an `Arrays.deepToString` method available in standard library.

Comment: thanks for your feedback I will definitely try it. I'm worrying though for for my ComplexMatrix(int rows,int cols) implementation.